# is it possible to stretch create_window() frame to size of parent (or root)?

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

i want to make my chatroom app gui resizeable.

i have a `canvas` and on it a `msg_frame` where all the messages will be put in.

the canvas is set on the root with `place()` so it stays relative to the root window size.
i want to make the `msg_frame` resize relative to the canvas (or root) also.

so when i resize the root window, the messages wont show up like this (blue is msg_frame):
[image]

but stick to the right side (close to the scrollbar).

this is my code (removed styling for readability):

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chatroom")
root.geometry("1200x800")

chat_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=580, width=1160)
msg_frame = tk.Frame(chat_canvas, bg="blue", height=550, width=1160)

# scrollbar
canvas_sb = tk.Scrollbar(top_frame, orient='vertical', command=chat_canvas.yview)
chat_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas_sb.set)

# placing the scrollbar and canvas
chat_canvas.place(relwidth=0.98, relheight=1)
canvas_sb.place(relx=0.985, relheight=1)

create msg_frame window on canvas
chat_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=msg_frame, anchor='nw', width=chat_canvas.winfo_reqwidth())

# resize canvas to fit to frame and update its scrollregion
def on_msg_frame_configure(event):
    # set canvas size as new 'stretched' frame size
    chat_canvas.configure(height=msg_frame.winfo_reqheight())
    chat_canvas.configure(scrollregion=chat_canvas.bbox('all'))

# my (not working) attempt to resize the blue msg_frame 
def on_top_frame_configure(event):
    msg_frame.configure(width=top_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), height=top_frame.winfo_reqheight())


# binds to resize widgets when root size changes
msg_frame.bind(sequence='<Configure>', func=on_msg_frame_configure)
top_frame.bind(sequence='<Configure>', func=on_top_frame_configure) # <-- not working
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after lots of tries i managed to get what i wanted. this is what i've done:

when creating a window, assign it a variable

```
canvas_frame = chat_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=msg_frame, anchor='nw', tags="msg_frame")
```

then bind the widgets as follows, with these configure functions:

```
def on_chat_canvas_configure(event):
    # set canvas size as new 'stretched' frame size
    chat_canvas.itemconfig(canvas_frame, width=event.width)
    canvas_scrollbar.pack_configure(side='right', fill='y')
    chat_canvas.pack_configure(side='right', fill='both', expand=True)


def on_msg_frame_configure(event):
    print('on msg frame')
    chat_canvas.configure(scrollregion=chat_canvas.bbox('msg_frame'))

# binds
chat_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: on_chat_canvas_configure(e))
msg_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: on_msg_frame_configure(e))
```

when the root window size changes, the the canvas' size changes also, and the configure event fires, calling `on_chat_canvas_configure()` function that changes the width of `msg_frame` on the canvas, while keeping the scrollbar and canvas' sizes relative to the root window.

when the size of `msg_frame` changes, the configure event of this widget fires and call `on msg_frame_configure()` function that simply updates the `scrollregion` of the canvas.

hope i explaned the logic correctly and clearly.